# Promise.all() keeps running even after error is thrown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

in my React component, I have this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const {
      dispatchGetCompanies,
      dispatchGetDocumentTopics,
      dispatchGetDataForCompanyTopicList,
      dispatchGetDocumentTypes,
      dispatchRequestComplete,
      dispatchRequestInProgress,
      dispatchRequestError,
    } = this.props;
    dispatchRequestInProgress()
    Promise.all([
      dispatchGetCompanies(),
      dispatchGetDocumentTopics(),
      dispatchGetDocumentTypes(),
      dispatchGetDataForCompanyTopicList(),
    ]).then(() => {
      dispatchRequestComplete();
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatchRequestError(error);
    });
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatchGetCompanies: (...args) => dispatch(getCompanies(...args)),
    dispatchGetDocumentTopics: (...args) => dispatch(getDocumentTopics(...args)),
    dispatchGetDataForCompanyTopicList: (...args) => dispatch(getDataForCompanyTopicList(...args)),
    dispatchDeleteCompanyTopic: (...args) => dispatch(deleteCompanyTopic(...args)),
    dispatchGetDocumentTypes: (...args) => dispatch(getDocumentTypes(...args)),
    dispatchRequestInProgress: (...args) => dispatch(requestInProgress(...args)),
    dispatchRequestComplete: (...args) => dispatch(requestComplete(...args)),
    dispatchRequestError: (...args) => dispatch(requestError(...args)),
  };
};
```

The action for getDocumentTypes is this:

```
export function getDocumentTypes() {
  return function (dispatch, getState, api) {
    return api.get('/document-type-metadata')
      .then(({data}) => dispatch(getDocumentTypesSuccess(data)));
  };
}
export function getDocumentTypesSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: GET_DOCUMENT_TYPES,
    payload: data,
  };
}
```

Reducer code is this:

```
function setDocumentTypes(state, action) {
  const {
    documentTypeMetadata
  } = action.payload;
  return state.merge({
    documentTypes: List(documentTypeMetadata),
    _metadata: Map({
      isFetching: false,
    }),
  });
}

export default function (state = Map({
  id: null,
  companyTopics: List(),
  companies: List(),
  topics: List(),
  documentTypes: List(),
  _metadata: Map({
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
  }),
}), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SECTION_IDENTIFICATION_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
      return setRequestComplete(state, action);
    case SECTION_IDENTIFICATION_REQUEST_IN_PROGRESS:
      return setInProgress(state, action);
    case SECTION_IDENTIFICATION_REQUEST_ERROR:
      return setError(state, action);
    case GET_COMPANIES:
      return setCompanies(state, action);
    case GET_DOCUMENT_TOPICS:
      return setTopics(state, action);
    case GET_COMPANY_TOPIC_LIST_DATA:
      return setCompanyTopicListData(state, action);
    case GET_DOCUMENT_TYPES:
      return setDocumentTypes(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The dispatchRequestError is similar; it sets the "error" object in the Redux store to whatever error is returned.
The problem I am having is that if the api call to getDocumentTypes returns back an error, I would expect the dispatchRequestError to immediately execute, with all the other promises (dispatchGetDocumentTopics, etc) being rejected. However, after the error is set, the other promises inside the `Promise.all()` still resolve, causing the `error` property to become undefined, which causes the error message that I'm showing on the page to appear, then quickly disappear.

What is going wrong?
Thank you

Comment: `Promise.all` does not *run* anything. You have four independent promises that are pending, if one of them rejects that does nothing to affect the other ones. It only affects the promise returned by `Promise.all` that was waiting for all four of them.